# Stabilizing a Decorative Garden Wall

Tags: landscaping

I am planning out a zen garden, and wanted something to block the view of our elevated patio, so if you are sitting out in the garden it will really be like being in a different world. I saw this design and really like the idea. [image: Bamboo and Wood Wall, https://www.bambooimport.com/en/bamboo-fencing-ideas-for-garden-patio-or-balcony]

Honestly, with my level of DIY experience, this is probably too ambitious of a project anyway, but how would one keep a large, decorative wall like this standing upright and stable in wind?

Comment: What wind speeds and length of time do you have/expect?  High winds and solid single walls usually do not go good together.

Comment: South Florida USA, so wind would be a big concern. In an ideal world it would still be easily portable or able to be disassembled and secured inside in preparation for a hurricane.

Comment: Keep it upright in the wind by sinking the support legs into concrete foundations. If it _has_ to be removable, sink a larger steel pipe in the concrete, then put the wall legs into the sleeves in the concrete. This way you can "just" lift it out of the sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Put a solid wall behind the bamboo screen.**

[image: cinderblock wall and bamboo screen]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lx_gHhgqZZE

You can build a cinderblock wall.  It will not blow down.  Then mount the bamboo screen on the wall.  The linked video assumes you already have such a wall and wish to conceal it with the bamboo.

Given that you don't really need a cinderblock wall, you could put up a lesser fence chosen for stability and low cost.  Mount your bamboo on that.    The idea is that the bamboo can just worry about looking good and the wall or fence can do the work.

Comment: Would the solid wall/fence need to be the full height of the bamboo as well? The patio floor is about 40 inches off the ground, and the top of the patio railing is about 80 inches from the ground. I was imagining using an 8 foot wall to hide the full patio, but I'd like it to be fairly close to flush with the patio, so I was thinking of doing the solid wall in the space under the patio

Comment: I pictured this wall in open space.  But that is not the case!  I am not sure a 40 inch wall will be better than just anchoring the bamboo screen directly to the patio floor and patio railing.   Take a look in the video how they put a wood strip to anchor he screen to,and do that for your patio floor edge.  Also, a bamboo screen is not a precious thing.  It will be cheap to replace if it gets destroyed or starts to look tired.

Comment: Yeah, the bamboo I'm less concerned about. It would be more if I tried to do the side panels. I was thinking 8ft 4x4 posts, either leaving the "window" panes open, or using frosted plexiglass to approximate the look of a Japanese shoji (paper door). The posts are heavy and could damage the house if the fell the wrong direction